# Binding variables access in Groovy script's defined classes

Tags: groovy

Given a regular Groovy script, is there a way to access its binding variables from classes defined inside the script itself?

The following snippet

```
class Example {
  def printBindings() {
    for (var in binding.variables) {
      println "$var.key - $var.value"
    }
  }
}
new Example().printBindings()
```

fails with the exception below:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: binding for class: Example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I can find without passing the script through to the method:

```
class Example {
  def printBindings( container ) {
    for (var in container.binding.variables) {
      println "$var.key - $var.value"
    }
  }
}
new Example().printBindings( this )
```

Comment: The problem is I'm dealing with 3rd-party scripts that I can't modify, and I have to inject bindings and make them available within script classes. :-/

Comment: Do you have a simple example? Having problems coming up with a test script to try things out in...

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because that's the only way to work around this issue, even if I can't really do it for my particular problem. Thanks anyway, Tim!